# Regex replacement in a custom tag

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a string that may contain one or more of the following tags:

```
<CHOICE [some words] [other words]>
```

I need to replace (C#) all occurrences of this tag as follows:

```
Example: I like <CHOICE [cars and bikes] [apple and oranges]>
Result: I like cars and bikes
```

```
Example: I like <CHOICE [cars and bikes] [apple and oranges]>, I also like <CHOICE [pizza] [pasta]>
Result: I like cars and bikes, I also like pizza
```

Basically, replace the entire tag with only the string appearing in the first set of brackets.

Looks like capture groups is the way to go but I wasn't able to understand how to make them work.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Regex is not a requirement, I thought it would be the best approach, but I see some comments telling me that it's not needed so any other suggestion will be just as fine. Thanks!

Comment: there are alternatives to regex here - simple use the indexes of the first open and closed bracket to get your text

Comment: There is more than one step to this regex or otherwise, and to tell you the truth you could probably do it quicker and maybe less code with a for loop

Comment: What have you tried, and what is not working?

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm trying to figure out how to approach this issue. First, I need to identify the tag that will be replaced as a whole, then replace it with the content of the first brackets. Then repeat for any istance of the tag if there are multiple tags in the same string.

So far I've only dealt with regex replacements such as `text = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "fixedvalue");` so I'm a bit lost...

Comment: are you using this on HTML or XML?

Comment: It's neither of those, but the strings may contain other kind of custom tags that can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get groups of Matches First, then for each Matched Group replace a first string in `[` and `]`

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(InputStr, @"<CHOICE(.*?)>");

foreach(Match Item in matches)
{
    MatchCollection matches1 = Regex.Matches(Item.ToString(), @"\[(.+?)]");
    string FirstOccurence = matches1[0].Groups[1].ToString();
    InputStr = InputStr.Replace(Item.ToString(), FirstOccurence);
}
```

Find the [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PwFv0r)

Comment: I think this works perfectly! I believe only the last substring needs to be tweaked as follows: Substring(1, matches1[0].ToString().Length - 2)

Comment: Sorry, I made a further edit as my original correction contained a mistake. Looks like it's "Length - 2".

Comment: evaluates to cars and bike <- instead of bikes

Comment: @ArthurGrigoryan Edited the answer. Please check it.

Comment: @Sting1 removed `.Substring`. Check the latest answer.

Comment: @ Sushant Yelpale Cool, fix the demo and check out what I've done :)

Comment: Looks way cleaner now! And it works perfectly. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun. Here is a school-yard `foreach` *state-machine*, with a *linear* O(n) *time complexity*.

```
var line = "I like <CHOICE [cars and bikes] [apple and oranges]>";

var result = new StringBuilder();
var state = 0;

foreach (char c in line)
{
   if (state == 0 && c == '<') state = 1;
   else if (state == 1 && c == '[') state = 2;
   else if (state == 2 && c == ']') state = 3;
   else if (state == 3 && c == '>') state = 0;
   else if (state == 0 || state == 2) result.Append(c);
};
```

**Output**

```
I like cars and bikes
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RCZtPS)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great for the first occurrence of the tag. With multiple tags (either if there are unrelated tags before, or multiple CHOICE tags) it has some issues but I think it's a good starting point to understand how to make it fully work. I didn't think of this approach at all.

Comment: @Sting1 yeah, this is only for fun as i am waiting for my lift. regex might be a good option too, i updated with a statemachine

Answer (score 0):

```
string pattern = @"\< *CHOICE *((\[(?<choice>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)\]) *)+ *>";

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

string source = "I like <CHOICE [cars and bikes] [apple and oranges]>";

var match = regex.Match(source);
if (match.Success)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups["choice"].Captures.Count; i++)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine(match.Groups["choice"].Captures[i]);
    }
    string replaced = regex.Replace(source, match.Groups["choice"].Captures[0].Value);

    Debug.WriteLine(replaced);
}
```

The output is:
cars and bikes
apple and oranges
I like cars and bikes

> \< *CHOICE *

matches "<" "zero or more spaces" "CHOICE" "zero or more spaces"

> ([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)

matches words and spaces

> ?<choice>

gives above group a name:choice

> \[(?<choice>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)\]

matches one choice in []

> ((\[(?<choice>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)\] *)

matches choices separated by zero or more spaces

> +

means you should have at lease one choice

> *>

you can have zero or more spaces at the end before ">"

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the best way to do that.

```
string text = "This is some dummy text with the choice <    CHOICE     [ white   black green     cyan ] [yellow green]>." +
            " The second choice <CHOICE [pink brown red] [blue cyan]>.";
string pattern = @"<\s*?CHOICE\s*\[\s*?(.+?)\s*?\].*?>";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, r => String.Join(" and ", r.Groups[1].Value.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

This is some dummy text with the choice white and black and green and cyan. The second choice pink and brown and red.

Comment: Try and test it now. Ready for production :D

Comment: How would you know Spaces to remove?

Comment: @Sushant Yelpale Didn't get what you meant, but Regex handles all the spacing except for those between the choice words which get processed by splitting and removing empty entries.

Comment: If there are more than 1 Consecutive Spaces in input String, One should not remove without Knowing what they are meant for. like you removed them from `<    CHOICE     [ white   black green     cyan ] [yellow green]>` in output

Comment: @Sushant Yelpale I can't think of any situation where we would want to keep extra spaces between choices, and thus I tried to eliminate accidents. I mean it's not a thing that would meet all particular cases. For example, what if choices were separated by comma and we wanted to get rid of it. We would definitely rewrite the above logic to meet the criteria.